# Disable formatting in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

In my Twig template comes variable *source*, which contains whatever source eg. php, js, html ... etc.
Source is formatted - with whitespaces and /r/n, but Twig renders it all in one line. I tried next:

```
{% autoescape false %}
{{ source }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

and

```
{% autoescape false %}
{{ source|raw }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

but didn't managed to success.
Here is output of `{{ dump(source) }}`:

```
string '$builder->add('availability', 'choice', array(
    'choices'   => array(
        'morning'   => 'Morning',
        'afternoon' => 'Afternoon',
        'evening'   => 'Evening',
    ),
    'multiple'  => true,
));' (length=219)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to render (or view) your page as HTML. HTML strips all extra whitespaces (tabs, spaces, line feeds). To save your formatting with spaces you need to use `<pre>` tag:

```
<pre>
{{ source|raw }}
</pre>
```

Comment: `{% autoescape %}` and `|raw` do the same thing. only one of them should be required.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov, thanks! I will try it when came home and report for results.